# Can I manage views based on permissions in OOTB Foundation 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, list-view

As problem fixes are implemented, we are uploading additional or modified documentation and procedures to a sharepoint site where our employees can review those changes.

We've got another sharepoint site where we log problems. I'd like to merge the two sites into a place where we log problems, and the solutions/results are posted for review as projects are completed.

By merging them, we would have a single document repository with views driven by status metadata. Developers can see ALL documents, end users only the ones marked "Resolved."

I envision it working like this:

Consider:
Doc001 - open
Doc002 - Resolved
User001 - developer, SP Site Admin
User002 - end user, SP Site Visitor

When User001 logs on, the landing page would appear with Doc001 and Doc002 (DeveloperView contains all docs). 
When User002 logs on, the landing page would appear with ONLY Doc002 (UserView contains all docs where status == "resolved").

We're using Foundation 2010, with very basic OOTB functionality. We do not have any capabilities to do custom coding in our envornment. Is displaying one of two pages, based on the permissions of the user accessing the data, something doable in our environment? Regeards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint does not provide an OOB way to display views based on permission. But you can work around this by creating 2 views. First view (DeveloperView) will be of all items for the Developers. Second view (UserView) will be filtered based on Status == Resolved i.e only the items with status set as resolved will be shown in the Userview.

Next, create a page and place a List View WebPart on that page with the UserView on the list. And give access on only that page to the users.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I'll be creating two separate pages, one of which only contains the user information and is for user consumption...am I understanding properly?

Comment: Yes, so basically the pages will be shown/hidden based on permissions.